# image floating out of parent div for no reason

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

The title may be a little bit unclear, but I have an `<img>` tag generated by the WordPress shortcode: `the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');` and I placed this inside a parent div, to give it the right place in the website.

single.php has this inside:

```
<div class="newsidebar">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
</div>
```

HTML output:

[image: htmloutputimg]

css styling for `.newsidebar`

```
.newsidebar {
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    height: 500px;
    margin: 4em 0;
}
```

expected output is just this image sitting inside my `.newsidebar` div, but actually it's stuck at the bottom of the page for no reason. There is no padding/margin pushing the img down, no position absolute with top/bottom styling.

Is there another css reason that I overlook why it wishes to sit ~1000px lower in the site then expected?

actual output on site:

[image: actual output]

What did I try to fix this?

giving the img:

positions,

margin,

top,

bottom,

but the only thing that actually got it to stay inside the parent was

```
.newsidebar > img {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

downside of this code, I don't want to use position absolute, as there are widgets/ other elements being added inside newsidebar. which will then hover above or below this image.

any CSS/JavaScript/jQuery solutions are helpful.

**edit** I fixed my issue using another WordPress function named `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` and adding that url to the background of a div inside my `.newsidebar` div. but I am still curious to find out why this `<img>` was taking a trip down my website.

Comment: Check all the css propieties applying to you image in the dev tool. It might heritate some of its classes (attachement-thumbnail, etc...)

Comment: no i've checked inside the devtools, there is no weird styling applied. as said in the question "there is no padding/margin pushing the img down, no position absolute with top/bottom styling"

Comment: My guess would be, that some JS Code is involved, that collects all of your `attachement-thumbnails` and adds them to that bottom bar.

Comment: Can you provide all CSS applied to that page and full HTML markup please?